# About fiber of a ring morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We know the definition of fiber of a ring morphism $A \to B$ given by $S^{-1}(B/PB)$ where P is in $Spec A$. We also know that in characterstic 0, the fiber of a flat ring morphism $A\to B$ is $(B/(P \cap A)B)_{P}$ where P is in Spec B. Does these two definitions are same? How? Your help will be greatfully acknowledged.